# Cut HTML Tags and wrap HTML tags again Part/1

Tags: php, html, regex

i try to convert the follow string

```
 <p>
     string
    <b>
      bold
        <em>italic string</em>
      also(bold)
    </b>
 </p>
```

to this string

```
 <p>
     string
 </p> <!--------------------------------------- insert -->
    <b>
      bold
    </b> <!------------------------------------ insert -->
        <em>italic string</em>
     <b> <!------------------------------------ insert -->             
      also(bold)
    </b>
 <p> <!---------------------------------------- insert -->
 </p>
```

i know that is not valid html, but i need this for my project.
... regex its a good way, but i just do not get solved.

the whole strcture will be dynamic,

my thinking was, regex

```
// open tag close
$regex = '<(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)>'

if ($1 != $3) {
$newString = <$1>$2</$1></$3> 
}
```

but don't work!

Comment: ...what exactly is the question?

Comment: is this same string always or dynamic ?

Comment: @Rogue  i need to insert dynamic a "TAG-Breakpoint" before open or close a antother TAG 

the string to be must convert istdynamic

Comment: Are you aware of the dangers of [parsing HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something which I think works is two successive replaces:

1.

```
^(\s*<(?!/))([^<]+)>(?=[^<]+\n)((?:(?!</\2>)[\s\S])*?)(?=\n *<)(?![^>]*</\2>)
```

Replace by:

```
$1$2>$3\n$1/$2>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tH3iO2)

2.

```
/[^>]+>$\n\K([^<>]*?)(^\s*)(?=</([^>]+)>)
```

Replace by:

```
$2<$3>\n$1$2
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wI1eX5)

[ideone render](http://ideone.com/cF46l2)

I'm not sure why ideone turns the `<>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and I don't know how to avoid it :(

But that works with your sample.

Comment: thanks for you quick feedback, you right with the example (see over) works, but with another text (valid HTML) works not ...

sample: 

'<p>
string <b>bold </b><em>italic </em>string <b>also</b>(bold) 
</p>'

Comment: @FooLing Can you put that in your question please? It's hard to read that in the comment :)

Comment: i did'nt find the button for this action ;)

what i mean .. your regex wroks only for my example, but not for another (valid) HTML-Strings

Comment: @FooLing I put some more safeguards on the first regex. Could you check that one?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a static string, then you might do as such in javascript,

```
          htmlstring.replace("<b>","</p><b>")
                    .replace("<em>","</b><em>")
                    .replace("</em>","</em><b>")
                    .replace("</b>","</c-b>")
                    .replace("</b>","</b><p>")
                    .replace("</c-b>","</b>");
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/z5Aba/1/. (Need to check the console)

Comment: thanks for your feedbacks, but the string is not static... its a dynamic generate string

Comment: You mean the whole structure will be dynamic or just the string parts like `string`, `bold` ..

Comment: the whole strcture will be dynamic, 

my thinking was, regex

<(*.?)>(*.)</(*.?)> 
if $1 != $3 then

$newString = <$1>$2</$1></$3> 

but don't work!